# Remove package from installation on hard drive from live CD

Tags: lubuntu

I tried installing Xen VM from one of the standard ubuntu repositories on my lubuntu distro. The problem is whenever I boot I reach an error on boot (not a 64bit CPU).

I would like to remove the Xen VM package from the computer, but I can't boot.

I assumed I might be able to do it from another Linux environment, so I'm presently running lubuntu off a live CD.

Could I remove the package and it's changes on the hard drive from the live CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a live CD and boot repair worked.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair